# Android : Widget and Service

Tags: android, service, widget

I have a widget that start into onUpdate method a service that read same datas from web and save it into preference and then this service must call onUpdate method of widget for update it with this datas. I use this code from service

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 5000, pi);
```

But this code don't call the widget's onUpdate method...why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to update the widget

```
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, YourAppWidgetprovider.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);           manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
```

updateViews is the RemoteViews object. Update this remote view with your data before you call the update.